# Different ways to assign pointer in C , using & or *?

Tags: c, pointers

In C , if i want a pointer reference to a variable

`int c = 12 ;
int *p ;
p = &c ;`

or i can do it this way

`int c = 12;
int p;
p=&c;`

in both case value of p is the address of c , can you please tell the problems i will be facing .

Comment: `or i can do it this way` - no, you can't

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it this way:

```
int c = 12;
int p;
p = &c;
```

This is not valid C to assign a pointer value to an integer object. Enable all your compiler warnings, the compiler has to give a diagnostic message for the invalid assignment.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, there is no problem as p is a **special type of variable which** can contain address. Thus here **p is called a pointer variable.**

In second case, **p is normal scalar variable** which cannot contain address. So there is a problem. Compiler implicitly will not be able to assign the address of **c** variable to the variable **p**

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `*` mean different things in different contexts.

`&` in a variable declaration (including in a function parameter) means "reference" or "by reference" in C++, and is not allowed in C. In C++, the type of `j` below is "int". It doesn't modify the type, but says "this is another name for existing data" rather than "create a space for new data".

```
int i = 5;
int &j = i; //C++ only: j is another name for i
int f(int & x); //f is a function that takes in an int by reference
```

`*` in a variable declaration means "pointer". The type of `int*` is "pointer to an int", while, again, the type of `int&` (C++ only) is `int`. It modifies the type.

```
int *p = NULL; //p is a pointer to an int, that currently points to nothing.
int f(int & x); //f is a function that takes in an int by reference
```

`&` in front of an existing variable means "a pointer to", or "address of". It's an operator, which can be thought of as a special kind of function. It takes in anything and returns a pointer to that thing.

```
int i = 5;
int *p = &i; //p points to i
int **pp = &p; //pp points to p
```

`*` in front of an existing variable means "what this is pointing to", also known as the dereference operator. Like `&`, it's an operator. It can only be applied to a pointer, and it returns what the pointer is pointing to.

```
int i = 5;
int *p = &i; //p points to i
int j = *p; //j copies what p is pointing to
```

So if I say `*&var`, that is the same as `var`, because it means "dereference the pointer to var".

Answer (score 0):

```
int c = 12; int p; p=&c;
```

introduces the risk of losing bits from the address of `c`.

If you really need to store an address as integer then use `uintptr_t` as target integer type, as it's guaranteed by the C standard to be wide enough to store an address:

```
int c = 12; uintptr_t p; p = (void*)&c;
```

`uintptr_t` comes in `<stdint.h>`.

> **7.18.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers**
>
> 1
>
> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> **intptr_t**
>
> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid
>   pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> **uintptr_t**
>
> These types are optional.

However to have this integer converted back to a pointer to an integer it casting needs to go via `(void*)`:

```
int * pi = (void*)p;
```