# Diffrence between pointer assignment in C

Tags: c, pointers

what is the difference between pointer assignments shown below:

```
int i = 5;
int *ptr = &i;
```

vs

```
int i = 5;
int *ptr;
ptr = &i;
```

vs

```
int i = 5;
int *ptr;
*ptr = &i;
```

I suppose 1st and 2nd are same but 3rd is different.So my question is what is the diffrence between 1,2 vs 3?

Comment: In 3 you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, therefore pointing on an address which you should likely not access, and you're writing the address of `i` inside. This will just crash your application since it doesn't have the authorization to write to this address. .

Comment: `*ptr = &i;` is invalid statement.

Comment: The first two are effectively the same.  The third is bogus, assigning a pointer to an integer at an indeterminate address (because `ptr` is not initialized, `*ptr` doesn't point anywhere determinate).  A crash is likely, but not inevitable.

Comment: *ptr = &i doesn't give any error in my compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different ways to assign pointer in C , using & or \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452418/different-ways-to-assign-pointer-in-c-using-or)

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20452591/1393400

Comment: Then you need to compile with more warnings enabled!  I would start with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion` on gcc or clang.

Comment: Those are not duplicates, because the problem here is that the third snippet dereferences an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @Davislor the third snippet is just a pure logical error. And such a question have been asked hundred times in many different ways.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I can believe that there’s a dupe, but neither of the two candidates mentioned so far is it. If someone finds a duplicate, I’ll vote to close. It is a very basic question, yes. But it looks on-topic and reasonably specific to me. YMMV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two statements do the same thing, but there are reasons (which I’ll get into) to prefer the first style to the second.  The third is **undefined behavior**, which is very bad.  And it also ought to be a type error.

If your compiler is accepting this code without a fuss, you’re not compiling with enough warnings turned on.  It should notice that you’re dereferencing an uninitialized pointer and also that you’re assigning a pointer to an `int` without a cast.  On gcc or clang, you might add the flags `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion` and `-std=c11` or whatever you’re targeting.

The statement `int i = 5;` is, in the third case, mostly irrelevant to what comes next. The declaration `int *ptr;` is an uninitialized pointer.  Then, `*ptr = &i;` dereferences that uninitialized pointer, which if you’re lucky will crash the program immediately, right then and there, allowing you to find the problem.  If you’re unlucky, it’ll muck up some other part of memory somewhere that’ll create a strange and unpredictable bug you can’t reproduce and no hint where it came from.

A good habit of defensive coding is to write as many of your variables as possible as *static single assignments*.  That is, whenever possible, you declare and initialize your variables once, as `const`, and never modify them again.  In this case, that would be:

```
const int i = 5;
const int * const ptr = &i;
```

This also eliminates a big category of bugs where I use the newer value of the variable where I meant to use the older one, or vice versa.  And the compiler cannot catch these for me.  If `i` and `ptr` only ever have one meaning, it’s impossible to mix up which meaning it has at any given time when I refactor.  As for efficiency, it’s a wash.  If I’m doing a calculation based on a value, I either will need the original value again, or I won’t.  If I do, overwriting it is a bug.  If I don’t, dependency analysis should determine that the compiler doesn’t need to keep the value around any longer.

You can’t always do this: one very common example is loop counters.  In those cases, a decent habit to get into (although you can find examples where I don’t follow my own advice religiously) is to always initialize everything to `0`, `NULL` or some other blatantly invalid value.  That way, if you accidentally use one before initializing it for real, at least the results will be wrong and reproducible.  So:

```
int i = 5;
int *ptr = NULL;
*ptr = &i; /* FIXME: Undefined behavior! */
```

On most OSes you’ll be targeting, this will at least crash your program immediately, at the place where the logic error occurs, making it easy to find.  (Since, in the past, my C and C++ answers have drawn the attention of one or two people who want to point out that the language standard does not *guarantee* this, I agree, it’s not portable.  But I’ve found it useful in practice.)  Otherwise, if you’re single-stepping through in the debugger, looking for the bug, it’ll be really obvious that the variable is uninitialized at the point of use, whereas if it just contains whatever garbage was on the stack, it might not be.

On the other hand, if your compiler can detect uninitialized variables being used, this habit might prevent it from doing so.